# Using Condition statements with Makefile targets

Tags: makefile

Hello i'm trying to use condition statements in my makefile to have it execute different make targets, but it skips over the condition and goes right to the else.

He's a general example of what i'm trying to do

```
ifdef ($(RUN_TEST))
all: install run uninstall 
else
all: install uninstall
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not indicate on what system you are running the Makefile, as there are slightly differing make programs available. Make can be run on linux and windows and comes in different variants.

However, I have worked with most variants, and there is a common way you can resolve your problem. You have to realise that the makefile is not a program executed in the conventional sequential manner. It is a series of declarations or definitions of actions to be performed at some future time. You cannot read through it in a sequential manner like a program. In particular the definitions of dependencies are not executed and cannot be embedded within statements, even pre-processed statements.

The best way to achieve what you want it to put the dependencies in a variable and set that variable conditionally, like this:

```
if ($(RUN_TEST))
ALL=install run uninstall
else
ALL=install uninstall
endif

all : $(ALL)
```

This should work on most implementations.

Comment: I actually found away around it using 

ifeq ($(origin RUN),undefined)
      all: install uninstall
else
      all:install run uninstall 
endif

Answer (score 0):

The GNU make [`ifdef` operation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Syntax.html#index-ifdef) takes the *name* of a variable to test; you are providing it the *expansion* of a variable.  You want to write it like this:

```
ifdef RUN_TEST
  ALL = install run uninstall
else
  ALL = install uninstall
endif
```

By using `$(RUN_TEST)` you're actually testing a variable named by the expansion of `RUN_TEST`.  So for example if `RUN_TEST` is set to `true`, then `ifdef $(RUN_TEST)` actually tests to see if the variable `true` is defined or not.